# What is the use case of cudaGraphicsRegisterFlagsWriteDiscard in cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage?

Tags: opengl, cuda

I'm fairly new to CUDA, but I've managed to display something generated by a kernel on the screen using OpenGL. I've tried several approach :

1. Using a PBO and an OpenGL texture (old style);
2. Using a OpenGL texture as a CUDA surface and rendering on a quad (new style);
3. Using a renderbuffer as a CUDA surface and rendering using glBlitFramebuffer.

All of them worked, but, while implementing #2, I erroneously set the hint as cudaGraphicsRegisterFlagsWriteDiscard. Since all of the data will be generated by CUDA, I thought this was the correct option. However, later I realized that I needed a CUDA surface to write to an OpenGL texture, and when you use a surface, you are requested to use the LoadStore flag.

So basically my question is this : Since I absolutely need a CUDA surface to write to an OpenGL texture in CUDA, what is the use case of cudaGraphicsRegisterFlagsWriteDiscard in cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage?

Comment: Using a renderbuffer as a CUDA surface and rendering using glBlitFramebuffer.
"use FrameBuffer" more precisely? because Renderbuffer has to be bound to FrameBuffer before it can be used with glBlit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation description](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html#group__CUDART__OPENGL_1gd7be3ca8a7a739d57f0b558562c5706e) seems pretty straightforward.  It is for one-way delivery of data from CUDA to OpenGL.

This [online book excerpt](http://books.google.com/books?id=CCVenzOGjpcC&pg=PA137&lpg=PA137&dq=cudaGraphicsRegisterFlagsWriteDiscard&source=bl&ots=pbu8HhfXJL&sig=EC3aQAwg_G6Z1cca7KLwDRbqqeM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vhekUc7OOqqYiAKwlIDICw&ved=0CEgQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=cudaGraphicsRegisterFlagsWriteDiscard&f=false) provides a similar explanation:

> Applications where CUDA is the producer and OpenGL is the consumer should register the objects with a write-discard flag...

If you want to see an example, take a look at the [postProcessGL](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#post-process-in-opengl) cuda sample.  In that case, OpenGL is rendering an image, and it's being post-processed (blur added) by cuda, before display.  In this case, there are two separate pathways for data flow.  In the OpenGL->CUDA case, the data is handled by the `createTextureSrc` function, and the flag specified is read-only.  For the CUDA->OpenGL case (delivery of the post-processed frame) the function is handled in `createTextureDst`, where a call is made to `cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage` with the `cudaGraphicsMapFlagsWriteDiscard` flag specified, since on this path, CUDA is producing and OpenGL is consuming.

To understand how the textures are handled (populated with data from the cuda operations via a `cudaArray`) you probably want to study the sequence of operations in `processImage()`.

Comment: Oh I see now. The kernel is not writing to the texture directly. It's using a simple array of float as a temporary storage. Once the kernel has run, the array of float is copied to the texture using `cudaMemcpyToArray`. Make sense. Thanks.

Comment: what's the difference between cudaGraphicsRegisterFlagsWriteDiscard and cudaGraphicsRegisterFlagsSurfaceLoadStore ? both of them can be used when write to openGL texture by cudaSurfaceObject_t

Comment: I've answered a similar question of yours [here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/reading-and-writing-opengl-textures-with-cuda/31746/19).

Comment: Thanks! So what flag should be use for OpenGL texture, and what for OpenGL renderbuffer?