# What Can I use to draw with cuda

Tags: c++, opengl, cuda, opencl, raytracing

I'm starting an university project, "real time ray tracing". I have to use CUDA, but what can I use for the graphics part?

I wanted to use OpenGL, in particular to draw pixel the glDrawPixels() funcion, however that function is deprecated, and I don't want to use deprecated funcions and also this function doesn't work with newest OpenGL's codes. I searched for a newest function in Opengl but (I think) there isn't one like that.

So I searched for OpenCL, but I haven't figured out if this library can help me.

So, What can I use to implement this project?

Comment: I can't add details, because this is the main on my problem, I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common simple rendering approach in OpenGL that is one level of complexity above `glDrawPixels` is to draw pixels to a texture, apply the texture to a quad and render from the quad.

[This presentation](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2009/presentations/1055-CUDA-Programmer-Needs-Know-OpenGL.pdf) will walk you through the steps, and as a bonus will show you how to use [CUDA/OpenGL interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19244191/cuda-opengl-interop-draw-to-opengl-texture-with-cuda), which will make your ray tracing animation run quicker, and should get you some brownie points at least on your university project.