# Missaligned error with surface object (Cuda/OpenGL interop)

Tags: opengl, cuda

I'm currently trying to interop Cuda and OpenGL on my project but it's proving to be a challenging task. I'm currently using the following code:

```
GLuint _frameTextureGL;
cudaGraphicsResource_t _frameTextureCUDA;

void GLInit(){
  glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
  glGenTextures(1, &_frameTextureGL);

  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _frameTextureGL);
  {
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, RES_X, RES_Y, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
  }
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

  CudaErrorCheck(cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage(&_frameTextureCUDA, _frameTextureGL, GL_TEXTURE_2D, cudaGraphicsRegisterFlagsWriteDiscard));
}


void DrawFrame(){

  LaunchKernel();

  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _frameTextureGL);
  {
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    {
      glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
      glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
      glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
      glVertex2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
      glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
      glVertex2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
      glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
      glVertex2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
    }
    glEnd();
  }
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

  glFinish();
  glutPostRedisplay();
}



LaunchKernel(){

  CudaErrorCheck (cudaGraphicsMapResources(1, &_frameTextureCUDA));  //error happens here

  cudaArray_t frameCudaArray;
  CudaErrorCheck( cudaGraphicsSubResourceGetMappedArray(&frameCudaArray, _frameTextureCUDA, 0, 0));
  cudaResourceDesc frameCudaArrayResourceDesc;

  frameCudaArrayResourceDesc.resType = cudaResourceTypeArray;
  frameCudaArrayResourceDesc.res.array.array = frameCudaArray;

  cudaSurfaceObject_t frameCudaSurfaceObject;
  CudaErrorCheck( cudaCreateSurfaceObject(&frameCudaSurfaceObject, &frameCudaArrayResourceDesc));

  KernelFunction<< <(RES_X * RES_Y / CUDA_THREADS_PER_BLOCK) + 1, CUDA_THREADS_PER_BLOCK >> >( frameCudaSurfaceObject);

  CudaErrorCheck( cudaDestroySurfaceObject(frameCudaSurfaceObject));

  CudaErrorCheck( cudaGraphicsUnmapResources(1, &_frameTextureCUDA));
  cudaStreamSynchronize(0);

}

__global__ void KernelFunction(cudaSurfaceObject_t frameCudaSurfaceObject){

  const int maxIndex = RES_X * RES_Y;
  int idx = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;

  if (idx > maxIndex) return;

  surf2Dwrite(make_float4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), frameCudaSurfaceObject, 0, 0);

  //surf2Dwrite(make_float4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), frameCudaSurfaceObject, (idx % RES_X) * 4, idx / RES_X);

}
```

The problem is that the surf2Dwrite on the kernel will cause other parts of my code to get an error.

With the code on it's current state my project runs but it doesn't show anything (which I suppose is normal since I'm not filling the surface object correctly).

But if I change my X & Y coordinates to anything other than (0,0) (by uncommenting the last line for example) then I get a "missaligned error" on the first line of the LaunchKernel function. (this error only shows on the second frame, not the first)

I've based my code on [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19244191/cuda-opengl-interop-draw-to-opengl-texture-with-cuda) so I assume that part to be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surface uses coordinates in bytes, not in elements. For `float4` the x coordinate should be `x * 16` (or `x * sizeof(float4)`), not `x * 4`:

```
surf2Dwrite(make_float4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), frameCudaSurfaceObject, 
            (idx % RES_X) * sizeof(float4), idx / RES_X);
```

Comment: Thank you, that seemed to fix the error. I changed my texture to use GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE and changed the surf2Dwrite to use just 4 bytes. I still can't see anything else apart from a black window but that's another problem.

Comment: If anyone in the future wants to use this code I fixed the black window problem by adjusting the coordinates of the glVertex2f's to the window resultion instead of using 1's.