# Bind already existing cudaTextureObject to texture in OpenSceneGraph(OpenGL) for rendering

Tags: c++, opengl, cuda, interop, openscenegraph

I have a `cudaTextureObject` (2D) which is the result of a chain of signal processing kernels. 
Now I would like to display this `cudaTextureObject` in our viewer with OpenSceneGraph.

All solutions for OpenGl interop with CUDA I found so far need to create a OpenGL texture first and then register this texture resource with CUDA, so that the resulting resource can be manipulated in kernels. For example described here: [CUDA/OpenGL interop, draw to OpenGL texture with CUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19244191/cuda-opengl-interop-draw-to-opengl-texture-with-cuda)

Is there a way in which I can just render the already existing cudaTextureObject (with its buffer) without copying it into a texture created by OpenSceneGraph (OpenGL)?

Comment: In a word, no. Interoperability only works with CUDA mapping OpenGL or Direct3D resources. Not the other way around