# which is faster: glBlitFramebuffer a renderbuffer or render a fullscreen texture?

Tags: performance, opengl, textures, render

which is faster and more efficient?

1. Using a OpenGL texture as a CUDA surface and rendering on a quad (new style);
2. Using a renderbuffer as a CUDA surface and rendering using glBlitFramebuffer.

Comment: Did you profile it? There won't be a definitive answer, it depends too much on the hardware, driver version and internal formats of screen and buffer

Comment: not yet. Thanks. most of the found solution uses a fullscreen texture.